# AS3 Starling URLLoader coercion failed

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I am trying to use the URLLoader class in my starling project however when I try:

```
loader.addEventListener(starling.events.Event.COMPLETE
```

I get:

```
Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.events::Event@e696e49 to starling.events.Event.
```

Code below:

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://domain.com/file.php");
var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();          
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
urlReq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
urlVars.txtVar = "12345";
urlReq.data = urlVars;
loader.addEventListener(starling.events.Event.COMPLETE, sendDataOnComplete);
loader.load(urlReq);
```

I am guessing it's because I am trying to mix starling events and flash events but I need to use Starling and I need to use URLLoader to POST/GET data from remote source.

Many many thanks.

Comment: Comment moved to an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't done anything with starling, but I know they have their own equivalent classes for all of the usual DisplayObjects we normally use in Flash. But since I assume you are using the Flash URLLoader class (and not a starling version of URLLoader), all you should be doing is using the normal Flash Event.COMPLETE ... As that is what is being dispatched by your loader.